# Build error with cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, android-youtube-api

I've updated my Cordova version to 8.0.0 and cordova-android to 7.1. Now the [cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player](https://github.com/ihadeed/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer) plugin is very unhappy, spitting out build errors like

> app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/bunkerpalace/cordova/YouTubeActivity.java:7: error: package com.google.android.youtube.player does not exist
>       import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
>
> symbol:   variable YouTubeIntents
>     location: class YoutubeVideoPlayer
>   /cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/bunkerpalace/cordova/YoutubeVideoPlayer.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
>   ```

I note that this plugin has not been updated in several years. At the same time, all the tutorials on the web still seem to recommend it. Unfortunately, the repo has no Issues feature, and I'm not even sure it's supported.

Does anyone know if this repo is alive, is compatible with the latest versions of Cordova and cordova-android, if there are any workarounds to this build error, and/or if there are any better recommended ways to display YouTube videos in a Cordova app?

Comment: Did you solved or founded alternative?